# How to check whether the connection is Wi-Fi or mobile internet in android studio

Tags: android

I am developing a web based mobile application but this application lacks mobile internet to run. Therefore, I want to offer the user to connect to Wi-Fi if he uses the application via mobile internet. But I don't know how to do it. Please give an example.

I didn't even know what to try because I couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: Hey bud, first of all provide information about your project like which framework, language you are working on. As there are libraries, plugins available for all frameworks for such kind of functionalities.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.